# No assets folder Bundling Angular 2 Applicaiton with newest webpack

Tags: angular, plugins, webpack, assets

i created with the newest Version of Angular-cli (Beta.32.3) an Angular 2 Porject. 
After then i used the **ng eject** command to generate a webpack.config.js file.

Now i can build my project wit npm run build.

But webpack doesnt copy my assets folder, where i have images. 
My GlobCopyWebpackPlugin should do this, or am i wrong?

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const { NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin, LoaderOptionsPlugin } = require('webpack');
const { BaseHrefWebpackPlugin, GlobCopyWebpackPlugin } = require('@angular/cli/plugins/webpack');
const { CommonsChunkPlugin } = require('webpack').optimize;
const { AotPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

const nodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');
const entryPoints = ["inline","polyfills","sw-register","styles","vendor","main"];




module.exports = {
  "devtool": "source-map",
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      ".ts",
      ".js"
    ],
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "resolveLoader": {
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "entry": {
    "main": [
      "./src\\main.ts"
    ],
    "polyfills": [
      "./src\\polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "./src\\styles.scss"
    ]
  },
  "output": {
    "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    "filename": "[name].bundle.js",
    "chunkFilename": "[id].chunk.js"
  },
  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "enforce": "pre",
        "test": /\.js$/,
        "loader": "source-map-loader",
        "exclude": [
          /\/node_modules\//
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": /\.json$/,
        "loader": "json-loader"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.html$/,
        "loader": "raw-loader"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(eot|svg)$/,
        "loader": "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(jpg|png|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani)$/,
        "loader": "url-loader?name=[name].[ext]&limit=10000"
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader",
          "less-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader",
          "stylus-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"paths\":[]}"
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader",
    "sass-loader"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader",
    "less-loader"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader",
    "stylus-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"paths\":[]}"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "test": /\.ts$/,
        "loader": "@ngtools/webpack",
        "exclude": [
          /\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    new NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      "template": "./src\\index.html",
      "filename": "./index.html",
      "hash": false,
      "inject": true,
      "compile": true,
      "favicon": "./src/assets/favicon.ico",
      "minify": false,
      "cache": true,
      "showErrors": true,
      "chunks": "all",
      "excludeChunks": [],
      "title": "Webpack App",
      "xhtml": true,
      "chunksSortMode": function sort(left, right) {
        let leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
        let rightindex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
        if (leftIndex > rightindex) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (leftIndex < rightindex) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    }),
    new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({}),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": "inline",
      "minChunks": null
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": "vendor",
      "minChunks": (module) => module.resource && module.resource.startsWith(nodeModules),
      "chunks": [
        "main"
      ]
    }),
    new GlobCopyWebpackPlugin({
      "patterns": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "globOptions": {
        "cwd": "**/src",
        "dot": true,
        "ignore": "**/.gitkeep"
      }
    }),
    new ProgressPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      "filename": "[name].bundle.css",
      "disable": true
    }),
    new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      "sourceMap": false,
      "options": {
        "postcss": [
          autoprefixer()
        ],
        "sassLoader": {
          "sourceMap": false,
          "includePaths": []
        },
        "lessLoader": {
          "sourceMap": false
        },
        "context": ""
      }
    }),
    new AotPlugin({
      "tsConfigPath": "src\\tsconfig.json",
      "mainPath": "main.ts",
      "hostReplacementPaths": {
        "environments\\environment.ts": "environments\\environment.ts"
      },
      "exclude": [
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "M:\\smeady\\src\\test.ts"
      ],
      "skipCodeGeneration": true
    })
  ],
  "node": {
    "fs": "empty",
    "global": true,
    "crypto": "empty",
    "tls": "empty",
    "net": "empty",
    "process": true,
    "module": false,
    "clearImmediate": false,
    "setImmediate": false
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?  I'm running into the exact same issue, except it only happens on Linux.  When I run my project on Windows 7, my assets folder gets copied just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I found the answer to my problem by reading this issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5811

Basically, I had to change my globOptions in webpack.config.js from:

```
new GlobCopyWebpackPlugin({
    "patterns": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
    ],
    "globOptions": {
        "cwd": "C:/Users/James/projects/mine/address-label-printer/src",
        "dot": true,
        "ignore": "**/.gitkeep"
    }
}),
```

to:

```
new GlobCopyWebpackPlugin({
    "patterns": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
    ],
    "globOptions": {
        "cwd": path.join(process.cwd(), "src"),
        "dot": true,
        "ignore": "**/.gitkeep"
    }
}),
```

Hope this helps